# JSF- Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandlink

```
<p:dataTable var="dataMap" id="dataTable" value="#{demoManagedBean.resultMap}">
<p:commandLink action="#{demoManagedBean.navigate}"   >
    <h:outputText value="#{dataMap['Name']}" /> 
</p:commandLink>
```

is not working  But

```
<p:dataTable var="dataMap" id="dataTable" value="#{demoManagedBean.resultMap}">
<p:commandLink action="#{demoManagedBean.navigate}"   >
    <c:set value="#{dataMap['Name']}" var="name" />
    <h:outputText value="#{name}" /> 
</p:commandLink>
```

is working..

I don't know which makes the first coding to be inactive

Comment: which primefaces version ?

Comment: And what does 'not working' mean

Comment: Show the getter for `resultMap`

Comment: What do you mean by 'is not working' ? What is the `name` var and what value is it supposed to have?